# Is using jQuery with Pixastic possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a set of link images (**HTML**):

```
<a href="#"><img src="test.jpg /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="test2.jpg /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="test3.jpg /></a>
```

They are partially transparent (**CSS**):

```
#a img {
    border: 0;
    opacity: .2;  
}
```

They're getting less transparent on hover (**jQuery**):

```
$('a img').hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.8,}, 200);
    });
```

The question is - how to add a blur on them using Pixastic (I don't want to use multiple layers and other hacks, just Pixastic)?

I know it works this way:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.8,}, 200);
    $(this).pixastic("blur");
```

But I want to animate bluring. How to de-blur (and I don't mean sharpen()) on mouseout?

I'm trying:

```
 $('# img').mouseout(
    function()
    {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 400);   
        $(this).pixastic("sharpen");
    });
```

But the pixastic thing doesn't seem to work on mouseouts. I know I'm interrupting jQuery's animation process, but don't know how to handle it.

Comment: did you try executing pixastic code on callback of animate? http://api.jquery.com/animate/#callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Pixastic is that it always replaces your original photo. But you can just easily create your own blur animation effect with canvas. Inside your link-element you need to place a canvas copy of the image-element. Changing the pixeldata to get a blur effect isn't very hard.

I think i just created a Dojo version of the effect you want in jQuery. You can see it here: http://westendorp.name/index.php?category=coding&page=coding/imageEffects 
I don't think it's hard to port this to jQuery though.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will help somebody: just chain animate after pixastic.

```
   $(this).pixastic("sharpen").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 400);
```